# Is there any way to sort items in Windows 8's jump lists?

Tags: windows-8, jumplist

This is the jump list of some of the files that I'm usually working with. However, it really gets frustrating when you try to skim and scan in those items to find what you're looking for.

[image]

Is there anyway to sort them out alphabetically?

Comment: Unfortunately drag and drop will be the quickest way

Comment: If you don't like Windows 8 jumplists then avoid Windows 10. They killed them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a free  third party tool called [Jump List Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/#download), it lets you sort and   add categorizations , customization in the jump list

[Here is a link](http://www.programmerfish.com/create-sort-jump-lists-in-windows-8-using-jumplist-launcher/) which explains step by step procedure with screen shots on how to use this amazing tool